# Python & JSON - Appending to String Object

Tags: python, json, append

Relatively new to using JSON & Python, but running into an issue trying to append to an existing JSON object. First, some pseudo-code:

1. Want to use a JSON "template" for each append, so that is created
2. The first item in a new list will always be this template (index 0)
3. Once a new record is found, the template is appended to the object and then populated

I've tried json.update and dict.append and just concatenating to a string, but I keep getting either list index out of range (current error with code below) or append errors.

Please help!

```
def parse(self, response): 
    # Create Store JSON template
    unit_JSON_template = {
        "Store": [
        {
            "ID": "",
            "Seller": 
            {
                "Name": ""
            },
            "Detail": 
            {
                "StoreURL": "",
                "Title": "",
                "Stock": "",
                "Other": "", 
                "Images": [ 
                {
                    "Url": "",
                    "Encode": "",
                    "Title": ""
                }
                ],
                "Request": 
                {
                    "DateTime": "",
                    "RequestHeaders": "",
                    "ResponseHeaders": ""
                }
            }
        }
        ],
    }

    # Convert template string to JSON
    unit_JSON_str = json.dumps(unit_JSON_template, indent = 4, separators = (", ", ": "), sort_keys = False)
    print(unit_JSON_str)
    unit_JSON_obj = json.loads(unit_JSON_str)
    unit_JSON = unit_JSON_obj

    # Create identifying information 
    record = response.url.split("/")[2] + "-" + response.url.split("/")[-2]
    record_timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%m%d%Y%-H%M%S")
    page_filename = f'{record}-{record_timestamp}.html'
    screenshot_filename = f'{record}-{record_timestamp}.png'

    # Parse data, load to JSON object for Insert to SQL
    data_units = response.xpath("//candy-stores")
    print("Units Found: " + str(len(data_units)))
    
    # Loop over each object and insert into JSON object (index 0 always template above)
    for i, data_unit in enumerate(data_units):
        i_1 = i + 1 #do this since template is always index 0
        unit_JSON.update(unit_JSON_obj)
        print(json.dumps(unit_JSON, indent=4))

        unit_JSON['Store'][i_1]['Detail']['Title'] = "Store Name"
        unit_JSON['Store'][i_1]['Detail']['StoreURL'] = "Unit"
        unit_JSON['Store'][i_1]['Detail']['Request']['DateTime'] = "12:00pm"
        unit_JSON['Store'][i_1]['Detail']['Other'] = "Additional Data"
        unit_JSON['Store'][i_1]['Seller']['Name'] = "ABC Candy"
```

Comment: can you add a printed out `data_units`?

Answer (score 0):

You are very much overcomplicating this. Inside your python code, don't use JSON, but a list of dicts. Convert to JSON when you need to provide said JSON.

Take a look at how I would handle this. A simple helper function to add a new dict item to the list of dict items.
I've included some examples on printing this, assigning a JSON string, and saving a JSON file.

You will need to handle the `images` in the `not_a_json_object`, I didn't include this part.

As for the `IndexError`, you do this `i_1 = i + 1` and then try to access the element on the list based on that.

```py
import json
from pprint import pprint


def new_dict_from_template(
    storeid="",
    sellername="",
    storeurl="",
    title="",
    stock="",
    other="",
    images=[],
    req_datetime="",  # named to prevent name collision
    requestheaders="",
    responseheaders="",
) -> dict:
    return {
        "Store": [
            {
                "ID": storeid,
                "Seller": {"Name": sellername},
                "Detail": {
                    "StoreURL": storeurl,
                    "Title": title,
                    "Stock": stock,
                    "Other": other,
                    "Images": images,
                    "Request": {
                        "DateTime": req_datetime,
                        "RequestHeaders": requestheaders,
                        "ResponseHeaders": responseheaders,
                    },
                },
            }
        ],
    }


def parse(self, response):
    # Create identifying information
    record = response.url.split("/")[2] + "-" + response.url.split("/")[-2]
    record_timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%m%d%Y%-H%M%S")
    page_filename = f"{record}-{record_timestamp}.html"
    screenshot_filename = f"{record}-{record_timestamp}.png"

    # Parse data, load to JSON object for Insert to SQL
    data_units = response.xpath("//candy-stores")
    print("Units Found: " + str(len(data_units)))

    # create a list
    not_a_json_object = []

    # Loop over each object and append to list
    for i, data_unit in enumerate(data_units):
        # Indexing is not really needed unless you use it in the JSON
        # you need to change the method call below
        # to match your data_unit
        not_a_json_object.append(
            new_dict_from_template(
                id="no idea",
                sellername="ABC Candy",
                other="Additional Data",
                req_datetime="12:00pm",
            )
        )


# note the [ and ] to make this a list of dicts
not_a_json_object = [new_dict_from_template()]
print(json.dumps(not_a_json_object, indent=4))
print("----------------------------------------")
not_a_json_object.append(
    new_dict_from_template(
        storeid="no idea",
        sellername="ABC Candy",
        other="Additional Data",
        req_datetime="12:00pm",
    )
)
print(json.dumps(not_a_json_object, indent=4))
print("----------------------------------------")
# just taking one element of the list is still a valid JSON
json_str = json.dumps(not_a_json_object[1], indent=4) 
print(json_str)

with open("somejsonfile.json", 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(json.dumps(not_a_json_object, indent=4))
```